# Transitionend based transition loop breaks in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, css-transitions, transition

I have very basic promise based self-calling function that:

- takes collection of divs with certain class
- checks whether they have just been moved left or right
- based on result makes choice to move (`transform: translate`) them
  with `classList.add()` / `classList.remove()`
- and on `transitionend` - calls itself

here is function:

```
function transitionTest(){
          console.log('called --- transitionTest() ');

          var dummies = document.getElementsByClassName('dummy'),
          count = dummies.length;

          if(window.cache==='right'){
              var transitionCollection=0;
              for(var i = 0; i < dummies.length; i++){
                  dummies[i].classList.remove('right');
                  dummies[i].addEventListener('transitionend', function(){ 
                      transitionCollection++; 
                      if( transitionCollection === dummies.length ){
                          transitionTest();
                      }  
                  });                  

              }              
              window.cache='';
          } else {
              var transitionCollection=0;
              for(var i = 0; i < dummies.length; i++){
                  dummies[i].classList.add('right');
                  dummies[i].addEventListener('transitionend', function(){ 
                      transitionCollection++; 
                      if( transitionCollection === dummies.length ){
                          transitionTest();
                      }  
                  });

              }        
              window.cache='right';

          }
```

**and here is [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66dom7ue/)**

### So, what is wrong?

- Nothing, if you are accessing via modern browser but **not** latest versions
  of Chrome on Windows
- Nothing, if you are accessing via latest versions of Chrome on Windows but **refrain from causing any mouse events** such as mouseenter/leave, click, even window `focus` event (e.g. if you stand still)
- If you do such, infinite left - right movement of dummy div will occasionally break, under unclear circumstances

What gets wrong:

Dummy `div`, which is moving left-right infinitely, on `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `click`, sometimes and sometimes not (exact conditions are unclear) will:

- go to end CSS value without transition and resumes normal operation after a while
- stop entirely and resumes normal operation after a while
- slow down (!? *yeah, I wish I was kidding* ) and stop/go to end CSS value

These errors are occurring in Chrome 45 (Win 7) and, less intensively Chrome 42 (Win XP) - which are platforms that I was able to test by now. Just to note, upper code does not need to be cross browser, I'm fully aware of implications.

Comment: I think that's the same problem that I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678578/css-transition-is-sometimes-skipped-in-chrome Looks like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @chrisklaussner I was assuming that this is bug in Chrome, but, you know rule of thumb - browser bug is the last one to blame. Maybe someone know something me and you don't. I saw your example, too bad Purple Tentacles workaround doesn't work to me.